# Why is AWS EC2 not working on iOS and MacOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So basically I'm writing a tool for managing some EC2 instances, nothing special.
I managed to get some AWS framework to build for MacOS (incredible that it is not officially supported) and I'm now trying to use the describeInstances() request of the framework.

I always get the same error :  `Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSEC2ErrorDomain Code=0`

- I've tried the same code on iOS, same issue.
- I've tried on a python script, using the Boto3 library, and no problem here, the function returns my instances and the descriptions.
- I already use AWSS3 and AWSSNS on the same MacOS project, with no issue.
- I have my policies set on IAM, for EC2 set on "fullAccess"

Here's the code:

```
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                         initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                          identityPoolId:kPoolID];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    AWSEC2 *ec2 = [AWSEC2 defaultEC2];

    AWSEC2DescribeInstancesRequest *request = [AWSEC2DescribeInstancesRequest new];
    [ec2 describeInstances:request completionHandler:^(AWSEC2DescribeInstancesResult * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@ = %@", @"EC2 describe Error", error);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@ = %@", @"EC2 describe Response", response);
        }
    }];
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason EC2 does not want to take the cognito pool is as a form of authentication, I had to connect using access and secret key to make it work.